# overriding equals() vs overriding compareTo()

Tags: java, overriding, equals, comparable

Why we MUST have to take an argument of type **Object** during overriding equals() method, but when we override compareTo() we can take an argument of the type we are sorting

```
   class Student implements Comparable { 
       String name; 
       int rollNum;
       // We can take here actual Student rather than Object
       public int compareTo(Object o){ 
           Student s = (Student)o; 
           return name.compareTo(o.getName());
       } 
       // We cant take an argument other than Object here
       public boolean equals(Object o){
       }
}
```

Comment: Different methods for different purposes.

Comment: Note for equals you would need a hashCode implementation too !

Comment: @StackFlowed Don't "need" (says the devil's advocate); although not having it also defined violates the Object contract.

Comment: Why do you say you can use the exact type when your code.. doesn't? There's a difference between `Comparable` and `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: yes.. but why method overriding rule is different for both of them? Is it only because equals() method is in Object Class and compareTo() in inside Comparable interface.

Comment: Do you know how generics work?

Answer (score 2):

`equals` method is coming from `Object` class, which is extended by all the objects since Java 1.0. Then there was no generics and `Comparable` interface is used mostly the way, in which class in parametrized by itself, for example:

```
class Student implements Comparable <Student> {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `foo.equals(bar)` asks, "Would you consider yourself equivalent to the object identified by this reference?"  By contrast, `foo.compareTo(bar)` asks "Should you be supported above or below the object identified by this reference?"

Any kind of object should be able to answer the first question when given any kind of reference.  If an instance of `Cat` is given a reference to a `FordPickupTruck` and asked whether it is equivalent, it wouldn't need to know anything about the `FordPickupTruck` class or any instances thereof, beyond the fact that an instance to one isn't an instances of `Cat`, to know that it wasn't equivalent to the object identified by the given reference.

The second question, by contrast, is generally only meaningful when comparing objects of the same type.  A `CalendarEvent` class might define `CompareTo` such that events which have occurred or will occur sooner will sort before later events, while a `Person` class might define `CompareTo` such that people are ranked alphabetically by name.  While a `Person` object would have no trouble determining whether it was equivalent to a particular `CalendarEvent` object (it would simply answer in the negative), there probably wouldn't be any meaningful way by which it could say whether it should be sorted before or after such an object.